# Lasers in 3D space game

Tags: opengl, 3d

I am creating this little 3d space shooter and am somewhat unsure on how to implement the laser beams.

I'm thinking about something along Star Wars and the like where mostly you shoot rather short laser beams but very many of those.

Should I create a "tube" for each of the beams, render them via instancing and give them a better look just with the shader?

How would you go on about this? I was rather perplexed that there was no good tutorial on this matter out there.

Comment: Related question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63997/laser-beam-end-points-problems/

Comment: Other two related questions: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/73395/41153 and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/83861/41153

Comment: The best thing to do is to simply **try** something. If it works then stick with it. Experiment first - solve later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also assume that "laser beam" is cylinder, and create a billboard for that:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/

Comment: This is the superior answer IMO!

Answer (score 5):

I would do this by rendering textured quads. A single laser beam would be two rectangles intersecting each other at the center by a perpendicular angle, each sharing the same texture of the laser beam.

[image]

Not very much to it, you can use instancing for them, with a very simple pixel shader which just samples the texture, oh and additive blending.